# How to Synchronize Data between Local DB and Remote DB in a C# Project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, synchronization, localdb

I have a WPF Project developed in C#. My task is to synchronize data from local database to remote database whenever the system is connected to the internet.

I am searching on this from a week and found that it can be resolved by adding Local Database Cache Template but it is removed from Visual Studio 2013 by Microsoft so I am stuck at this problem.

Comment: You can add the Microsoft Sync Framework to your project via NuGet.

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you please guide me through the steps to do the synchronization ?

Comment: Make an effort on your own behalf and post back when you run into a specific issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Microsoft Sync Framework is not showing in the Nuget Packages Dialog boxes..can you help me how to include that ?

Comment: `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution ...`. Choose the `Search Online` box and type the name of the package. It will show up. Install it for projects of your choice.

Comment: @Celdor there are 3 options which one should i install ?

Comment: @AhmadCheema I take it as you have managed to find the packages. I cannot answer on which version of Microsoft Sync Framework you should install in your project. I guess all three version are from Microsoft. Perhaps one version will be dedicated to VS2013, >NET, ASP.NET.MVC or WPF version etc. You have to investigate this by yourself, googling each version and see which one fits your requirements and/or scenario.

Comment: I think you may need the MSF Redistributable and the MSF Database Providers Redistributable, with one being the core elements and one being specifically for databases.  I've never used it myself though.  I just know what I know by doing research.  That said, I've been aware of MSF for some time, so I knew what to look for in the first place.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i have installed both the packages but still the Local Database Cache Template is not showing while adding new item to project

Comment: I never said or even implied that the Local Database Cache item template would appear as a result.  You are supposed to now use the MSF to do your syncing.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i think Synchronization will not be done in this way..do you know any other way i.e through SQL management Studio ?

Comment: As with your more recent question, `please` don't `randomly` format words in your question using `the` inline `code` tool - it's for code, classnames, variables, console i/o etc. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer thanks for your suggestions